# XML parsing format using php

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I am trying to parse Xml file using PHP but whenever i runs the code mit gives me error: invalid argument supplied for foreach()

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>  
<Rows>
<Row Code="10004" Name="EDEN 46cm TROUGH  Terracotta"  />
</Rows>
```

PHP code:

```
$xml =  simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents('XML/STKCatigories.xml'));
$i = 0;
   foreach($xml->Rows->Row as $key=>$product) {

  echo '<li>'.anchor ('/shop/listings/'.$product->Code,$product->Name).'</li>';

}
```

I couldn't understand where i am wrong.Kindly help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
$xml =  simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents('XML/STKCatigories.xml'));
$prifix = '/shop/listings/' ;
foreach ( $xml as $row ) {
    $attr = $row->attributes();
    printf('<li>%s</li>', anchor($prifix . $attr->Code, $attr->Name));
}
```

Comment: Brilliant.But it is giving me $attr->Name repeatedly as $attr->Name contains repeated category name for each product.How can i avoid duplication of $attr->Name in this?

Comment: @9 Digit if i get the full xml i can tell you a better approach

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me.I couldn't post the XML here due to some restriction.I will appreciate if you could follow this link and recommend a better solution here...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12883586/xml-complex-parsing

Comment: @Baba.Could you please help me with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26372398/oop-challenge-how-to-nest-using-foreach-in-php-mysql-result-set

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access tag attributes rather than explicit values.
Try something like:

```
$str = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>  
<Rows>
<Row Code="10004" Name="EDEN 46cm TROUGH  Terracotta"  />
</Rows>
XML;


$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);

foreach($xml->Row->attributes() as $a => $b) {
    echo $a,'="',$b,"\"\n";
}
```

Output:

> ```
> SimpleXMLElement Object
> (
>     [Row] => SimpleXMLElement Object
>         (
>             [@attributes] => Array
>                 (
>                     [Code] => 10004
>                     [Name] => EDEN 46cm TROUGH  Terracotta
>                 )
>
>         )
>
> )
> Code="10004" Name="EDEN 46cm TROUGH Terracotta"
> ```