# XML complex Parsing

Tags: php, xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [distinct in Xpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812122/distinct-in-xpath)

I am trying to extract data from my XML file using PHP. I want to get unique `ProductRange` based on `WebCategory` from my XML file. But the PHP code written below generate duplicate/repetitive results. I don't know where I am making mistake! Here is the code :

XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<Rows> 
<Row Code="10000" Name="HTC Wildfire S-A510E " ProductRange="HTC" ProductSubRange="Wildfire" WebCategory="Mobiles" WebDescription="Available in black and white.lightweight." Productlength="46mm" ProductWidth="16mm" ProductHeight="21.000" Weight="400gm" Description="Pck: 12   Plt: 1152" />
<Row Code="10001" Name="HTC Wildfire" ProductRange="HTC" ProductSubRange="Wildfire" WebCategory="Mobiles" WebDescription="Available in black and white.lightweight." Productlength="46mm" ProductWidth="16mm" ProductHeight="21.000" Weight="400gm" Description="Pck: 12   Plt: 1152" />
<Row Code="10002" Name="Samsung Galaxy S3" ProductRange="Samsung" ProductSubRange="Galaxy" WebCategory="Mobiles" WebDescription="Available in black and white.lightweight." Productlength="46mm" ProductWidth="16mm" ProductHeight="21.000" Weight="400gm" Description="Pck: 12   Plt: 1152" />
<Row Code="10003" Name="Samsung Galaxy S2" ProductRange="Samsung" ProductSubRange="Galaxy" WebCategory="Mobiles" WebDescription="Available in black and white.lightweight." Productlength="46mm" ProductWidth="16mm" ProductHeight="21.000" Weight="400gm" Description="Pck: 12   Plt: 1152" />
<Row Code="10004" Name="Samsung Galaxy S1" ProductRange="Samsung" ProductSubRange="Galaxy" WebCategory="Mobiles" WebDescription="Available in black and white.lightweight." Productlength="46mm" ProductWidth="16mm" ProductHeight="21.000" Weight="400gm" Description="Pck: 12   Plt: 1152" />
<Row Code="10005" Name="Samsung Galaxy Tabloid" ProductRange="Samsung" ProductSubRange="Galaxy Tabloids" WebCategory="Gadgets" WebDescription="Available in black and white.lightweight." Productlength="46mm" ProductWidth="16mm" ProductHeight="21.000" Weight="400gm" Description="Pck: 12   Plt: 1152" />
<Row Code="10006" Name="Apple Ipad 3" ProductRange="Apple" ProductSubRange="Tabloids" WebCategory="Gadgets" WebDescription="Available in black and white.lightweight." Productlength="46mm" ProductWidth="16mm" ProductHeight="21.000" Weight="400gm" Description="Pck: 12   Plt: 1152" />
<Row Code="10007" Name="Apple Iphone 4S" ProductRange="Apple" ProductSubRange="Iphone" WebCategory="Mobiles" WebDescription="Available in black and white.lightweight." Productlength="46mm" ProductWidth="16mm" ProductHeight="21.000" Weight="400gm" Description="Pck: 12   Plt: 1152" />
<Row Code="10008" Name="Apple Iphone 3G" ProductRange="Apple" ProductSubRange="Iphone" WebCategory="Mobiles" WebDescription="Available in black and white.lightweight." Productlength="46mm" ProductWidth="16mm" ProductHeight="21.000" Weight="400gm" Description="Pck: 12   Plt: 1152" />
<Row Code="10009" Name="Miscrosoft XBOX 360 Elite" ProductRange="Microsoft" ProductSubRange="XBOX" WebCategory="Consoles" WebDescription="Available in black and white.lightweight." Productlength="46mm" ProductWidth="16mm" ProductHeight="21.000" Weight="400gm" Description="Pck: 12   Plt: 1152" />
<Row Code="10010" Name="Sony Playstation 4" ProductRange="Sony" ProductSubRange="Playstation" WebCategory="Consoles" WebDescription="Available in black and white.lightweight." Productlength="46mm" ProductWidth="16mm" ProductHeight="21.000" Weight="400gm" Description="Pck: 12   Plt: 1152" />
<Row Code="10011" Name="Sony PSP Go" ProductRange="Microsoft" ProductSubRange="PSP" WebCategory="Consoles" WebDescription="Available in black and white.lightweight." Productlength="46mm" ProductWidth="16mm" ProductHeight="21.000" Weight="400gm" Description="Pck: 12   Plt: 1152" />
<Row Code="10012" Name="Sony Erricsson Satio" ProductRange="Sony Ericsson" ProductSubRange="Satio Series" WebCategory="Mobiles" WebDescription="Available in black and white.lightweight." Productlength="46mm" ProductWidth="16mm" ProductHeight="21.000" Weight="400gm" Description="Pck: 12   Plt: 1152" />
<Row Code="10013" Name="TomTom Go Live Gl2" ProductRange="TomTom" ProductSubRange="Go Live" WebCategory="Navigation" WebDescription="Available in black and white.lightweight." Productlength="46mm" ProductWidth="16mm" ProductHeight="21.000" Weight="400gm" Description="Pck: 12   Plt: 1152" />
</Rows>
```

I want to get unique `ProductRange` based on `WebCategory` from my XML file. But the PHP code written below generate duplicate/repetitive results. I don't know where I am making mistake!

PHP Code:

```
  <?
 $xml =  simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents('XML/products.xml'));
 $prifix = '/categories/listings/' ;
 $cat=array();
 foreach ($xml as $row) {
 $attr = $row->attributes();
 if (!in_array((string)$attr->WebCategory, $cat)){
  printf('<li>%s</li>', anchor($prifix . $attr->Code, $attr->ProductRange));
  $cat[] = (string)$attr->WebCategory;
 }
 }
 ?>
```

**PLEASE NOTE:**
I want to extract `ProductRange` based on given `WebCategory` e.g I want to show all ProductRange according to their Webcategory like this select SQL query:

```
     "select ProductRange from XML where WebCategory='Mobiles'"
```

and it could give me distinct "ProductRange"(Not repetitive results) based on XML like this:

Htc
Samsung
Iphone

and so... I tried my best but failed to generate unique "ProductRange" based using the coding approach mentioned above.

Please correct me where i am wrong and kindly guide me where I need to make change to get unique `ProductRange` as mentioned above.

Comment: How about a xpath query?

Comment: That XML is invalid. You seem to be missing a start tag for `Rows`

Comment: @Quentin Sorry.I forgot to add <Rows> in xml while writing.i have edited as you mentioned.Is there any way i could avoid repetition in records?

Comment: @Quentin Please can you help with this:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13181833/challenging-issue-xml-data-sorting-using-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
$list = groupBy($xml, "WebCategory");
foreach ( $list['Mobiles'] as $product ) {
    printf('<li>%s %s</li>', $product->Code, $product->Name);
}
```

Output

10000 HTC Wildfire S-A510E

10001 HTC Wildfire

10002 Samsung Galaxy S3

10003 Samsung Galaxy S2

10004 Samsung Galaxy S1

10007 Apple Iphone 4S

10008 Apple Iphone 3G

10012 Sony Erricsson Satio

Function Used

```
function groupBy($xml, $categoryName) {
    $xml = new \SimpleXMLElement($xml);
    $category = array();
    foreach ( $xml as $row ) {
        $attr = $row->attributes();

        if (! isset($attr->$categoryName)) {
            trigger_error("$categoryName does not exist in XML");
            break;
        }

        $category[(string) $attr->$categoryName][] = $attr;
    }
    return $category;
}
```

[See live Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Fkj83F)

Comment: Brilliant & logical answer..thank you Baba.I really appreciate your help.bless

Comment: You are welcome anytime .. is there any other thing i can help you with @Bilal Khalid

Comment: @Baba.i have tried $xml =  simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents('XML/products.xml')); before using groupBy function as i am embedding external XML file but it gave me error.What will i need to do if i use values from query string??I mean i am using codeigniter and want to get different webcategories from my uri segment.I appreciate your help.Bless

Comment: Just use `groupBy(file_get_contents('XML/products.xml'), "WebCategory")` fixed to code for namespace

Comment: @Baba.Brilliant .Bless you Baba.you are a magician.

Comment: Coool .. glad i was able to help

Comment: @Babai need your help for this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13394651/updating-mysql-database-using-php-codeigniter-xml